# Create SQL compact database on fly from WPF

Tags: wpf, sql-server-ce

I am trying to create a SQL compact database (and tables further) on fly from a WPF application. I have installed SQL compact 4.0 and Visual Studio 2012.

Does anyone have some sample code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SqlCeEngine.CreateDatabase method to create a database file programitically, and then use SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery to execute "CREATE TABLE" statemenents etc.

Comment: Hi Erik, Sorry for the repeated posts! I had an additional question - is SQL Compact supported by Windows 8? If not, what do you think could be the alternatives? Thank you once again!

Comment: Yes, it is supported with Windows 8 WPF applications, but not with Windows Store apps.

Comment: Thanks once again Erik!